# Does a parenthesized expression in Javascript return a reference?

Tags: javascript

I understand that a parenthesized expression in Javascript returns the result of evaluating the expression in parentheses:

```
x = ( 1, 2, 3 );
```

will evaluate the three expressions above, and return the result of the last one: '3', as mentioned in some other posts.

The following example code from [SlickGrid](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example10-async-post-render.html) contains something I'm not quite sure I understand:

```
  $(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
      var d = (data[i] = {});
      d["title"] = "Record " + i;
      d["n1"] = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
      d["n2"] = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
      d["n3"] = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
      d["n4"] = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
      d["n5"] = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
    }
    grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
  })
```

In particular the expression:

```
var d = (data[i] = {});
```

appears to return a reference to the associative array initialized in the parenthesized expression.

Is that indeed what is going on?  Is there a more detailed explanation of this?  Is there a reason to do this instead of something more obvious, like creating the associative array 'd', and then setting it to 'data[i]'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. With the line:

```
var d = (data[i] = {});
```

The variable `d` and `data[i]` will both end up referring to the same empty object created by `{}`.

In JavaScript the `=` operator both sets the variable on the left and returns the value being set. This means you can do an assignment in the middle of another expression, possibly with parentheses to ensure correct order of operation.

In your example the parentheses are optional - the following would have the same result because the associativity of `=` is right to left:

```
var d = data[i] = {};
```

Another arbitrary example is doing an assignment in a function call's argument:

```
alert(d = "hello");
```

Or when assigning an object reference you can use the result to operate on the object involved:

```
var d;
(d = {}).prop1 = "test";
console.log(d.prop1);   // prints "test"
```

Comment: Many thanks, especially for the extra examples.  That last one would definitely have thrown me for another loop!

Comment: Note that this is not what [reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7) means, especially returning a reference means that you can use e.g. `delete` operator on it. The distinction of value/reference types as is done in Java is actually not useful in Javascript because in Javascript it is impossible to observe any difference.

Comment: Thanks @Esailija. How would you suggest I rephrase the sentence introducing my last example, and other similar sentences?

Comment: I think that is fine, what I was referring to is the value/reference distinction in the second paragraph. What is returned is the return value of the expression on the right-hand side.

Comment: @Esailija - Fair enough. I'll just drop the "/reference" part and leave it at that for now.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a short hand.
Your code

```
var d = (data[i] = {})
```

Is equal to

```
 data[i] = {};
 var d = data[i];
```

Comment: These are not equivalent, the setting of a property might fail which leaves `d` in different state than it is left in first snippet

Comment: Do I have an example of what? A property assignment failing?

Comment: A property assignment fails when `data` is a primitive, sealed, inextensible, or a frozen object when the property doesn't already exist or if the property exists then the assignment will fail when the property is not writable or the object is frozen. Then on the second line, you try to retrieve `data[i]`, but if the property assignment failed, then that will not be what you wanted. But in the first example, the assignment to the  variable always works even if the property assignment fails. So that's why they are not equivalent.

Comment: Here's an example that uses frozen object to produce different result http://jsfiddle.net/zgdKB/

Answer (score 0):

It makes the code shorter, but more difficult to read.  It's a common hack.  People generally try to avoid variables that will only be used once; especially if they can keep the line under 80ish characters.

```
var d = (data[i] = {});
```

is equivalent to,

```
var d = {};
data[i] = d;
```

---

In other languages, you would commonly see something like this:

```
function(str) {
    if (trimmed=str.trim()) {
        console.log(trimmed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes It does
Try the following code

```
var theObject={a:"hhelo",b:"no"}
hello={{a:"blah"},theObject}
console.log(hello)
//Object {a: "hhelo", b: "no"}
hello.a="b";
console.log(theObject)
//Object {a: "b", b: "no"}
```

So yes, it does return a reference

Answer (score 0):

You are right about the reference (it's nothing special about the parentheses, it's just that the assignment operator returns what was last assigned so you can set multiple values to the same thing: `x=y=3;`), but I cannot think of a good reason to write code this way.  A little bit of reordering of assignments, and you have essentially have the same thing, and it's trivial to split into two lines:

`var d = {},data[i] = d;`